# Import .png file into R Markdown

Tags: r, image, png, r-markdown

I've been trying to import an image into R Markdown using the code

`![](C:/Users/Amanda/CSC95/cities.png)`

but it keeps returning Error: unexpected '[' in "!["

Do I need to load a specific package to use the "![]" call? I've loaded the following libraries:

```
library("network")
library("sna")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("ggplot2")
library("grid")
library("GGally")
library("sand")
library("intergraph")
```

Comment: We'd need to see the context in where you're using this code. If you're doing it in an "r" block, it won't work.

Comment: Just expanding on @hrbrmstr's comment: The `![](path)` syntax isn't R, it's markdown. You're getting an R code error, so make sure you close `\`\`\`` your R chunk before using any markdown code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "r block". But I've written all of my code in one chunk in R Markdown, so it's all between     ```  ```. I tried to include a screenshot of it here, but couldn't figure that out, either!

Comment: Raw markdown has to be outside back-ticked blocks. Try moving it outside of one of them and see what you get.

Comment: I've tried it outside of the chunk in R Markdown; in a new script; and in the Console, but it keeps returning the same error.